# What is the int* here?

Tags: c++

So I know that a pointer is:

```
 int *someNumber;
```

but I have run accross some code with:

```
int* pOutputData = nullptr;
byte* pOutputDataByte = nullptr;
```

What does int* mean?

Is that some kind of array of int? Is it a pointer to the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int *` and `int*` are the same thing. The whitespace doesn't change anything.

`int *` can be used either as a pointer to `int` or as a pointer to the first element of an array of `int`s.  How a variable is used is context-dependent. Judging by the variable names, I'd guess that `someNumber` points to a single `int` and `pOutputData` points to an array.

Comment: `int*` is *always* a pointer to an `int` object. That `int` object may or may not be the first element (or any element, for that matter) of an array.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It might also be a pointer *behind* an `int`-object, or `NULL`...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Touché.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same

White space does not mean anything in c

```
int    *   num    ;
int *num;
int* num;
```

All the above statements are same!

We use int* as default; mainly in data structure, to avoid confusion.

Comment: In C, the conventional spacing is `int *num;` because that reflects the grammar. In C++, the conventional spacing is `int* num;`, because that's what Bjarne Stroustrup prefers. Either is ok -- but don't write `int* foo, bar;`, which defines `foo` as an `int*` and `bar` as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Always read pointer variables from right to left

```
int *p means p is a pointer to an int

char *p means p is a pointer to a char
const int *p means p is a pointer to an integer constant

int * const p means p is constant pointer to an int
```